# OpenGL. gluLookAt function not working

Tags: glulookat

This is an image which I draw with my program:

[IMG] http://i62.tinypic.com/j163j8.png [/IMG]

It is supposed to be 3D. When I try to check it with gluLookAt:

```
GL.glClear(GL.GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT | GL.GL_DEPTH_BUFFER_BIT);  
GL.glLoadIdentity();
GL.glMatrixMode(GL.GL_MODELVIEW);

glu.gluLookAt(
5.0, 2.0, 2.0,
0.0, 0.0, 0.0,
0.0, 0.0, 0.0);

figura(drawable);   //Drawing figure 
GL.glFlush();
```

It only shows white screen, or a messed up figure for a second, then it goes off. If I undestand good first 3 coords shows point of view, second 3 shows viewing destination and third 3 shows rotation axis. But this function only messes everything up.

Thanks for answers.

Comment: Third 3 are the "up" vector, try `glu.gluLookAt(5.0, 2.0, 2.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 1.0, 0.0);`

Comment: @AnthonyVallée-Dubois That would be a valid up vector if the eye was on the same XZ plane as the target, ie. {5, 0, 2} instead of {5, 2, 2}.

Comment: @schmop Maybe I'm wrong as it's been a while but it's my understanding that the up vector is recomputed by `gluLookAt()` to be perpendicular to the direction vector such as `side = cross(dir, up); up = cross(side, dir);`.  See :http://www.opengl.org/wiki/GluLookAt_code

Comment: @schmop In any case computing it yourself isn't wrong and your answer is spot on.

Comment: @AnthonyVallée-Dubois Oh. That's very handy! Haven't used gluLookAt in 10 years myself...

Comment: @AnthonyVallée-Dubois The documentation only states _the direction described by the up vector projected onto the viewing plane is mapped to the positive y axis so that it points upward in the viewport. The up vector must not be parallel to the line of sight from the eye to the reference point._ Might be optimistic to assume it does that by itself, but I don't really know.

Answer (score 1):

The last three parameters aren't exactly the rotation, but the "up" vector. If you do not want a distorted view, the up vector should be perpendicular to your direction vector, which here is {-5, -2, -2}. Among all the perpendicular vectors, the one you will choose will define the rotation as you call it.

In your example, the most upward perpendicular vector (the one you would use in a first person game for instance) would be **{-.323, .937, -.129}** after normalization. I computed it first by finding the "left" vector (cross product between absolute up {0, 1, 0} and the direction), and then as the cross product between the direction and "left".

Comment: `gluLookAt()` ortho-normalizes the up vector relative to the eye vector. There's no need to do that manually. See http://www.manpagez.com/man/3/gluLookAt/.

Comment: @RetoKoradi Okay. That wasn't so clear from the OpenGL reference pages.